# Oracle Database Change Notifications only sent every 15 minutes, not immediately

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm registering a listener for Oracle Database Change Notifications through JDBC (using the EclipseLink implementation of JPA, Oracle 11.2.0.3, Oracle JDBC thin driver 11.2.0.4).

I'm getting notifications, but all of them in one chunk every 15 minutes. The 15 minutes are based on absolute time, regardless of when I start listening. It seems like the job sending the notifications only runs at a fixed interval of 15 minutes on the server.

If I register a PL/SQL procedure directly on the server to receive notifications, the notifications are instant.

What options do I have, to reduce the interval? I'm aiming for instant or every few seconds. Are there any configuration options for the corresponding job that I'm missing?

Comment: The database publishes a change notification when the underlying transaction commits. There is a delay from the point of the commit of the transaction, and the receiving and processing of the database change event. This delay is dependent on the database machine, its load, and the mid-tier machine and its load. Make sure whether there is sleep() is being called in your implementation.